# Undefined C Type in cross-compiled c-shared library

Tags: go, shared-libraries

I am currently working on a project that involves using both PHP and GO. Specifically, I am trying to call some functions written in GO from my PHP application, which is deployed in Docker on Ubuntu 22.04.

To accomplish this, I cross-compiled the GO code from macOS. However, whenever I attempt to call the GO functions, I receive an error message stating that there is an undefined C type "_Fcomplex" at line 48.

I have included my code and the header file that was generated below. If anyone has any suggestions or solutions to this issue, I would be extremely grateful. Thank you in advance.

main.go

```
package main

/**
#cgo linux LDFLAGS: -Wl,-unresolved-symbols=ignore-all
*/import "C"
import (
    "fmt"
)

//export print
func print(out *C.char) {
    fmt.Println("[GO print] " + C.GoString(out))
}

//export sum
func sum(a C.int, b C.int) C.int {
    return a + b
}

func main() {}
```

header file:

```
/* Code generated by cmd/cgo; DO NOT EDIT. */

/* package Go */


#line 1 "cgo-builtin-export-prolog"

#include <stddef.h>

#ifndef GO_CGO_EXPORT_PROLOGUE_H
#define GO_CGO_EXPORT_PROLOGUE_H

#ifndef GO_CGO_GOSTRING_TYPEDEF
typedef struct { const char *p; ptrdiff_t n; } _GoString_;
#endif

#endif

/* Start of preamble from import "C" comments.  */




/* End of preamble from import "C" comments.  */


/* Start of boilerplate cgo prologue.  */
#line 1 "cgo-gcc-export-header-prolog"

#ifndef GO_CGO_PROLOGUE_H
#define GO_CGO_PROLOGUE_H

typedef signed char GoInt8;
typedef unsigned char GoUint8;
typedef short GoInt16;
typedef unsigned short GoUint16;
typedef int GoInt32;
typedef unsigned int GoUint32;
typedef long long GoInt64;
typedef unsigned long long GoUint64;
typedef GoInt64 GoInt;
typedef GoUint64 GoUint;
typedef size_t GoUintptr;
typedef float GoFloat32;
typedef double GoFloat64;
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#include <complex.h>
typedef _Fcomplex GoComplex64;
typedef _Dcomplex GoComplex128;
#else
typedef float _Complex GoComplex64;
typedef double _Complex GoComplex128;
#endif

/*
  static assertion to make sure the file is being used on architecture
  at least with matching size of GoInt.
*/
typedef char _check_for_64_bit_pointer_matching_GoInt[sizeof(void*)==64/8 ? 1:-1];

#ifndef GO_CGO_GOSTRING_TYPEDEF
typedef _GoString_ GoString;
#endif
typedef void *GoMap;
typedef void *GoChan;
typedef struct { void *t; void *v; } GoInterface;
typedef struct { void *data; GoInt len; GoInt cap; } GoSlice;

#endif

/* End of boilerplate cgo prologue.  */

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

extern void print(char* out);
extern int sum(int a, int b);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

that's the way, how I try to call it from PHP with included header:

```
\FFI::cdef(
           file_get_contents($libPath . "libutil.h"),
           $libPath . "libutil.so"
);
```

But if I only define the exported function, it works fine:

```
\FFI::cdef(
          "void print(char* p0); int sum(int p0, int p1);",
            $libPath . "libutil.so"
        );
```

command for cross-compile:

```
docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/Go -w /Go -e GOOS=linux -e GOARCH=amd64 golang:1.20 env CGO_ENABLED=1 go build -v --buildmode=c-shared -o libutil.so
```